# Changing default margins in template

Tags: margins, templates, default, changepage

I need to change the margins on a template for at school-report. Right now it looks like it thinks it's a book, because every other side startes its margins to far in on the paper.

This is the only commands I see, could determine the margins:

```
\documentclass[final, danish]{packages/DocLayout} 


\usepackage{packages/mygraphics}
    \tikzexternalize           
\usepackage{derivative

}
```

We've tried putting in the geometry package, like this: \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

But that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Those lines of code looks familiar. I wrote that report template when I was studying :D It uses `scrreprt` in `Doclayout`. I think there is a DVI option in the komascript package. Setting it to like `DVI=14` should do it.

Comment: Correction: It should be `DIV=14` not `DVI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [AAU report template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/aau-report-template/wvfjytzrkwmg) which I wrote 2 years ago. In `DocLayout` it uses the `scrreprt` from KOMAscript

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ProvidesExplClass{packages/DocLayout}{2020/07/04}{1.0}{Sideopsaetning}

\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrreprt}

\LoadClass[twoside, open=right, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
```

You will need to look into the KOMA-script  manual to find a way to change the margins. After a little searching I found the `DIV` option. Setting it to 14 should give a small margin. But you can change the value to your liking.

```
\documentclass[final, danish, DIV=14]{packages/DocLayout}
```

There might be other ways to set the margin in KOMA script, but I never looked into it as I preferred the standard.

**UPDATE**
If you want even margins, you need to change from a two sided report style to a one sided report style (even margins). In `DocLayout` at the `\LoadClass` line, change `twoside` to either `twoside=semi` or `oneside`

```
\LoadClass[twoside, open=right, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt} % change twoside to either twoside=semi or oneside
```

You will also need to apply the same change to the `\KOMAoption{twoside}` line in `frontpage.tex`

```
\KOMAoptions{twoside = semi}
\begin{forside}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
        \insertfigure*[width = 0.3\columnwidth]{example-image-1x1}
    \end{figure}
\end{forside}
\KOMAoptions{twoside} % change twoside to either twoside=semi or oneside
```

Comment: That's the one :)

but I'm looking for a way to get even margins on all pages. This just makes the margins smaller, unfortunately. 

Is that even possible in KOMA-script?

Comment: @HelenaSønderupLauridsen I made an update to the answer. If it didn't solve your issue, you can delete the two `\KOMAoptions{...}` in `frontpage.tex` and load geometry as you did in your question. (It's those two line that prevents geometry from making the changes)

Comment: Thanks ! that did it :)